# Need pattern matching in Ant for copying only parent folders

Tags: ant

I want to copy only the parent folders names from source and then create the folders with those names in a destination directory.

Ex: 
source
   - folder_1
     - sub_1
   - folder_2
     - sub_2
   - folder_3
     - sub_3

destination
   - folder_1
   - folder_2
   - folder_3

Could you let me know the pattern matching for this requirement in ANT.

Regards,
Satya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do what you ask will depend on how you intend to use the directory list once you have it,
but it sounds like you need a [dirset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html).  Here's an example build file snippet:

```
<property name="src.dir" value="src" />
<dirset id="my.dirset" dir="${src.dir}" includes="*"/>
<echo message="${toString:my.dirset}" />
```

Specifying `*` for the includes attribute will pick up only directories at the top-level under `${src.dir}`.  Then, for example, the copy task can then be used to copy those (empty) directories somewhere:

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}" >
    <dirset refid="my.dirset" />
</copy>
```

Comment: Yes, that was really helpful in getting the folder names from source, but I actually wanted to create the folders with the names in ${my.dirset}

Comment: @Satya - the copy will create the directories. I doesn't copy contents, just empty directories.